# Importing Node.js SDK into Typescript running in Node server gave error "ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I'm working on a Node.js SDK for server side usage, and running into this issue "**ReferenceError: require is not defined**" when trying to import it into my express app using Typescript. Initially I didn't have .d.ts files generated so I imported Typescript and generated the declaration files, but still got the error. My index.js in the SDK package:

```
const myDep = require('./myDep');
const client = function (sdkKey) {
    const c = {};
    c.do = (user) => {};
    return c;
}

module.exports = client;
```

The generated index.d.ts file looks like this:

```
export = client;
declare function client(sdkKey: any): {
    do(user: any): void;
};
```

This is the tsconfig.json in my SDK package:

```
{
  "include": ["src/**/*", "src/index.d.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "outDir": "./dist"
  }
}
```

I'm using npm link to import it in my node server running typescript, and using import in my app.ts file with

```
import * as mySDK from 'my-node-js-sdk';
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out in the end and it was fixed by adding a index.d.ts file for type declaration. Also found a couple places in my project where I was using ES6 exports instead of module so had to fix those as well.